# How to install Xerox workcentre 5020

Tags: drivers

Cups doesn't have a driver for WorkCentre 5020b.  But the printer is detected by Ubuntu cups and the config utility.  What should I do to install this printer to my Desktop system?

I want this set up as as local printer via USB on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you can get the drivers here for 5030 not sure for 5020 but might work?

http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-5735-5740-5745-5755/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en&contentId=118162&from=downloads&viewArchived=false

Myself I installed a 5755 doing this:
http://crazymadeagle.blogspot.com/2013/07/install-xerox-workcentre-5755-in-ubuntu.html